# Compress directory into tar.gz file in memory with python

Tags: python, tarfile

Trying to compress a filesystem directory into a `tar.gz` file and keep it in memory. Why, because I don't want to pollute the filesystem with a temporary file.

I am looking into `tarfile` package but I don't seem to get it done:

```py
import io
import tarfile

fo = io.BytesIO()
tar = tarfile.open(fileobj=fo, mode="w:gz")
tar.add(path)
```

Does not seem to work as I intend...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved with this snippet:

```py
import io
import tarfile

path = "/tmp/foodir" # this is a directory

file_io = io.BytesIO()
with tarfile.open(fileobj=file_io, mode="w|gz") as tar:
    arcname = os.path.basename(path) # keep path relative (optional)
    tar.add(path, arcname=arcname)
file_io.seek(0)
```